# In Unity Physics.gravity for x & z directions are not working in one script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have one Sphere and I wanted to change gravity(in X & Z) according to Tilt(Input.acceleration). But its not working. For changing the gravity I am using the following code:

```
if((Input.acceleration.x) > 0)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(9.81f, 0, 0);
    }
    if((Input.acceleration.x) < 0)
    {
        Physics.gravity = new Vector3(-9.81f, 0, 0);
    }
```

and for Z:`if((Input.acceleration.y) > 0)
        {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 0, 9.81f); 
        }
        if((Input.acceleration.y) < 0)
        {
            Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, 0, -9.81f);
        }`

I m writting these code in FixedUpdate function.
Can anyone tell me where I m making mistake? I m new to unity as well.

Comment: Is your sphere a rigidbody? And have you tried debugging to see whether the if statements are ever true?

Comment: Yes I am using rigidbody. yes I tried debugging as well, its true for each if statemet.

Comment: My main problem is that Physics.gravity is not working correctly for both directions(x & Z) together. Can anyone please help me resolving this so that gravity works fine with changing direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly from the comments, your problem is that gravity is working, but only on one axis (x or z) at a time. In order to get gravity working simultaneously for more than one axis at a time, try the code bellow:

```
Vector3 newGravity = Physics.gravity;
if((Input.acceleration.x) > 0)
    {
        newGravity.x = 9.81f;
    }
else if((Input.acceleration.x) < 0)
    {
        newGravity.x = -9.81f;
    }
else
    {
        newGravity.x = 0;
    }

if((Input.acceleration.y) > 0)
    {
        newGravity.y = 9.81f;
    }
else if((Input.acceleration.y) < 0)
    {
        newGravity.y = -9.81f;
    }
else
    {
        newGravity.y = 0;
    }

if((Input.acceleration.z) > 0)
    {
        newGravity.z = 9.81f;
    }
else if((Input.acceleration.z) < 0)
    {
        newGravity.z = -9.81f;
    }
else
    {
        newGravity.z = 0;
    }

Physics.gravity = newGravity;
```

However this will give the maximum gravity even for a small tilt. If you want the gravity to gradually grow depending on the angle of the tilt, you'll need to multiply 9.81f with a variable.

Comment: Thanks Steven for the code. Its works, but now the problem is that when I am tilting the device the sphere takes a curve path & changes the direction, but I want the sphere to move in a stright path. Can you plz tell me what shall I do for this?

Comment: you could try having only the largest of the 3 work, by comparing `Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.x)` with `Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.y)` and `Mathf.Abs(Input.acceleration.z)` to find which is highest. Not sure if this would work, but it's worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

I take [zero credit for this](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/52083-resolved-accelerometer-to-affect-gravity-or-world-rotation), in turn it was pulled from Unity iOS Example (linked in the forum post I linked) that does not appear to be up anymore:

```
public float force = 9.8f;
void FixedUpdate ()
{
    Vector3 dir = new Vector3(Input.acceleration.x,0.0f,Input.acceleration.y);
    Physics.gravity = dir * force;
}
```