# How to make Unity3d move objects on a table?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am working on a tabletop game that user controls using accelerometer in the phone. It is pretty similar to Labyrinth on iOS.

The scene contains a tabletop created using planes and cubes, and a sphere as a ball. As it works in Labyrinth game, on tilting phone ball should drop to the tilted side, while the camera stays centered to table. I am trying to do similar thing where user tilts the phone, and objects on table move to tilted side.

Currently, I add the x and z component to Physics.gravity on tilt. Sadly, this change in gravity does not affect the ball which stays put on the table. Use gravity is selected for the ball, and it drop down from height to the tabletop initially and then comes to halt. After the initial drop, ball does not react to any gravity change.

I have also tried rotating the whole table, but using transform.rotate does not work either. The table rotates perfectly, alongwith the camera, but the ball stays put hanging in the air. So, currently I am out of my depth about the issue.

Is there any other way to allow tilt action registered, so that ball moves to the tilted direction? I cannot use addforce function, as there are multiple objects which need to react to tilt, and it will be difficult to keep track of that many addforce calls. How else can I get it working?

Comment: What about friction on the ball and the table? Check out physics materials on these objects.

Comment: Good idea. Will try to play with them to make the ball move more realistically. Although, I found the issue with help from Jerdak. My gravity change line was affecting just the table, instead of whole scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15682664/in-unity-physics-gravity-for-x-z-directions-are-not-working-in-one-script/15773445#15773445) for some related information.

As for why your sphere is sticking to the table, can I assume your sphere has a rigidbody?  If so, you need need to wake it up:

> if (rigidbody.IsSleeping())rigidbody.WakeUp();

Ideally you would make that call only after detecting a change in orientation/gravity, not every frame.

Comment: thanks. will try wakeup call after changing gravity. btw, any other simpler way to use tilt controls, that I missed?

Comment: Simpler?  Not likely, unless there a 3rd party library I'm not aware of.  If you want physics, use tilt to affect gravity.

Comment: Great. It works now. I was actually updating gravity on the table, instead of global gravity. Got it working after adding the movement script to ball.

Also, as it stands, ball keeps rolling even after gravity is nullified. Is drag the best way to do it?

Comment: I don't have any physics material added to table. Currently it is just a plane with normal physics settings.

Comment: Multiple settings can affect ball rolling.  Mass, drag, surface material friction.  There isn't a "best way" per se, I'd say play around with the 3 values I mentioned to get a realistic result.  You might also consider creating a gravity "ramp" where a tilt's affect on gravity isn't linear.  Which is to say, maybe a tilt of [0,0.1] affects gravity by 5%, from [0.1,0.5] it has a 50% affect, etc.  This would need to be a smooth transition so that your ball doesn't leap around.  The intent here to smooth out small motions from user's hands being jittery.

Comment: Thanks. Will try to play with material more. It is doing okay as of now. Time to flesh out the scene before carrying on with smoothing out controls.